# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?

Tags: http, ssl, netty, starttls

I am netty `3.10.6` version, while communicating to server i am getting following error:

```
Decoding WebSocket Frame opCode=10
2019-04-30T14:31:36,002 UTC DEBUG (New I/O worker #5) [netty(?:?)] Component:DASHBOARD [org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder] Decoding WebSocket Frame length=0
2019-04-30T14:31:36,002 UTC DEBUG (New I/O worker #2) [netty(?:?)] Component:DASHBOARD [org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler] SSLEngine.closeInbound() raised an exception after a handshake failure.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.closeInbound(SSLEngineImpl.java:1561)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1451)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1315)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:852)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.messageReceived(SimpleChannelHandler.java:142)
    at com.atomiton.sff.imp.netty.SffRawMetering.messageReceived(SffRawMetering.java:149)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at com.atomiton.sff.imp.netty.NettyTransport$NettyPipeline.sendUpstream(NettyTransport.java:914)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
2019-04-30T14:31:36,003 UTC DEBUG (New I/O worker #4) [netty(?:?)] Component:DASHBOARD [org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder] Decoding WebSocket Frame opCode=10
2019-04-30T14:31:36,004 UTC DEBUG (New I/O worker #4) [netty(?:?)] Component:DASHBOARD [org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder] Decoding WebSocket Frame length=0
2019-04-30T14:31:36,004 UTC WARN  (New I/O worker #2) [SffTcpServer(log:855)] Component:DASHBOARD IO error in null+7012320048641541604:ssl<NioAcceptedSocketChannel[id: 0xaf52a017, /180.151.199.170:56987 => /172.31.14.2:9000]; Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2019-04-30T14:31:36,044 UTC DEBUG (New I/O worker #1) [netty(?:?)] Component:DASHBOARD [org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler] SSLEngine.closeInbound() raised an exception after a handshake failure.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.closeInbound(SSLEngineImpl.java:1561)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1451)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1315)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:852)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.messageReceived(SimpleChannelHandler.java:142)
    at com.atomiton.sff.imp.netty.SffRawMetering.messageReceived(SffRawMetering.java:149)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at com.atomiton.sff.imp.netty.NettyTransport$NettyPipeline.sendUpstream(NettyTransport.java:914)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
2019-04-30T14:31:36,044 UTC WARN  (New I/O worker #1) [SffTcpServer(log:855)] Component:DASHBOARD IO error in null+7012320048641541607:ssl<NioAcceptedSocketChannel[id: 0x14620731, /180.151.199.170:56986 => /172.31.14.2:9000]; Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the 'error' is actually **debug** statement. 
If you do not want to ignore it, you can try to decrease the client connection timeout (to become lower than the server connection timeout).